# Prove or contradict the following statements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Need some help for this question

Prove or contradict the following statements

1. ($A$ $\setminus$ $C$) $\cup$ ($B$ $\cap$ $C$) = ($A$ $\cup$ $B$) if and only if 
   [($A$ $\cap$ $C$)$\setminus$B] $\cup$ [ $B$ $\setminus$ ($A$ $\cup$ $C$) ] = $\emptyset$
2. ($A$ $\setminus$ $C$) $\cup$ ($B$ $\cap$ $C$) = ($A$ $\cup$ $B$) if and only if 
     $B$ $\setminus$ ($A$ $\cup$ $C$)  = $\emptyset$

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: under what circumstances can the union of two sets be empty?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Both sets are empty set. Is it correct?

Comment: @measure2012: do you assume that all sets are nonempty?

Comment: Correct, measure2012.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is false. For example, you could use $A=\{1,2\}$, $C=\{2,3\}$ and $B=\{3\}$. Then, $B-(A\cup C)=\emptyset$ but $A-C=\{1\}$ and $B\cap C=\{3\}$, the union of which is not equal to $A\cup B = \{1,2,3\}$.

The first one is true. Note that $(A-C)\cup(B\cap C)=A\cup B$ is equivalent to condition (L) "$A\cup C\supseteq A\cup B$ and $B\cup C^c\supseteq A\cup B$". Moreover, the RHS of the "if and only if" is equivalent to condition (R) "$B\supseteq A\cap C$ and $A\cup C\supseteq B$".

To show (L) $\iff$ (R) proceed as follows.

(R) $\implies$ (L): If $A\cup C\supseteq B$, then also $A\cup C\supseteq A\cup B$ and from $B\supseteq A\cap C$ follows $B\cup C^c = B\cup C^c\cup B\supseteq (A\cap C)\cup C^c\cup B = A\cup C^c\cup B$, so that $B\cup C^c\supseteq A\cup B$.

(L) $\implies$ (R): Conversely, if $A\cup C\supseteq A\cup B$, then also $A\cup C\supseteq B$. Finally, assume that $x\in A\cap C$, so that $x\in A$ and $x\in C$. Then $x\in B\cup C^c$ - but $x$ cannot be in $C^c$, so it must be in $B$, hence $A\cap C\subseteq B$.

I hope this should all be true.